# Read frequency of input in digital pins

Tags: analogread, voltage-level, digital, frequency, voltage

This is a somewhat theoretical question:
Let's say I have some sensor that sends digital signals to one of Arduino's digital ports.
Now, I don't know the frequency it sends those signals in.
For example, the frequency of the sensor output could be 100Hz, so every 1/100 of a second it varies the voltage (or keeps the old voltage if the next signal is the same as the previous one), but it could just as well be 200Hz.
Would Arduino be able to faithfully read the digital signal regardless of its frequency? Or is there a conventional frequency that digital devices usually use for output?
Wouldn't it be the case that if Arduino expects 100Hz signal, but the signal is 200Hz it would miss half the inputs?
For: (1 0 1 0 0 1...) wouldn't it see: (1 1 0) - that is skip every other input because it's sampling rate would be too slow by half?
Thanks kindly for your help..

Comment: What do you mean by “digital signal”? Some kind of synchronous serial transmission protocol? SPI maybe? Or I2C? Or maybe an asynchronous one, like logic level UART? Or is it a custom protocol? Your question will start to make sense only once you specify how the data is supposed to be clocked in your protocol.

Comment: *so every 1/100 of a second it varies the voltage (or keeps the old voltage if the next signal is the same as the previous one),* - are you asking about measuring voltages or frequencies?

Comment: @Nick, let's assume that the 1 voltage is high enough (but not too high) for Arduino to register a 1, and the 0 voltage is also within the threshold for Arduino to register a zero (say 5V for HIGH and 0.5V for LOW). It's the frequency of the signal I'm concerned with.

Comment: @Edgar, I have in mind just a generic digital sensor - let's say one that measures temperature and sends a digital signal to Arduino at some unknown frequency.

Comment: A “generic” digital sensor doesn't mean anything. Digital sensors usually come with either SPI or I2C interfaces. Sometimes asynchronous serial. All those are well defined communication protocols. There are _rules_ stating how the sender should notify the receiver about _when_ precisely the data line is to be sampled. The Arduino has hardware support for these protocols, but other protocols have to be implemented in software (e.g. one wire). So forget about your meaningless “generic” and tell us what serial protocol you intend to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 Hz is pretty trivial. See [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers).

This sketch can detect frequencies up to about 5 MHz:

```c++
// Timer and Counter example
// Author: Nick Gammon
// Date: 17th January 2012

// Input: Pin D5

// these are checked for in the main program
volatile unsigned long timerCounts;
volatile boolean counterReady;

// internal to counting routine
unsigned long overflowCount;
unsigned int timerTicks;
unsigned int timerPeriod;

void startCounting (unsigned int ms) 
  {
  counterReady = false;         // time not up yet
  timerPeriod = ms;             // how many 1 ms counts to do
  timerTicks = 0;               // reset interrupt counter
  overflowCount = 0;            // no overflows yet

  // reset Timer 1 and Timer 2
  TCCR1A = 0;             
  TCCR1B = 0;              
  TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;

  // Timer 1 - counts events on pin D5
  TIMSK1 = bit (TOIE1);   // interrupt on Timer 1 overflow

  // Timer 2 - gives us our 1 ms counting interval
  // 16 MHz clock (62.5 ns per tick) - prescaled by 128
  //  counter increments every 8 µs. 
  // So we count 125 of them, giving exactly 1000 µs (1 ms)
  TCCR2A = bit (WGM21) ;   // CTC mode
  OCR2A  = 124;            // count up to 125  (zero relative!!!!)

  // Timer 2 - interrupt on match (ie. every 1 ms)
  TIMSK2 = bit (OCIE2A);   // enable Timer2 Interrupt

  TCNT1 = 0;      // Both counters to zero
  TCNT2 = 0;     

  // Reset prescalers
  GTCCR = bit (PSRASY);        // reset prescaler now
  // start Timer 2
  TCCR2B =  bit (CS20) | bit (CS22) ;  // prescaler of 128
  // start Timer 1
  // External clock source on T1 pin (D5). Clock on rising edge.
  TCCR1B =  bit (CS10) | bit (CS11) | bit (CS12);
  }  // end of startCounting

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
  {
  ++overflowCount;               // count number of Counter1 overflows  
  }  // end of TIMER1_OVF_vect


//******************************************************************
//  Timer2 Interrupt Service is invoked by hardware Timer 2 every 1 ms = 1000 Hz
//  16Mhz / 128 / 125 = 1000 Hz

ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_vect) 
  {
  // grab counter value before it changes any more
  unsigned int timer1CounterValue;
  timer1CounterValue = TCNT1;  // see datasheet, page 117 (accessing 16-bit registers)
  unsigned long overflowCopy = overflowCount;

  // see if we have reached timing period
  if (++timerTicks < timerPeriod) 
    return;  // not yet

  // if just missed an overflow
  if ((TIFR1 & bit (TOV1)) && timer1CounterValue < 256)
    overflowCopy++;

  // end of gate time, measurement ready

  TCCR1A = 0;    // stop timer 1
  TCCR1B = 0;    

  TCCR2A = 0;    // stop timer 2
  TCCR2B = 0;    

  TIMSK1 = 0;    // disable Timer1 Interrupt
  TIMSK2 = 0;    // disable Timer2 Interrupt

  // calculate total count
  timerCounts = (overflowCopy << 16) + timer1CounterValue;  // each overflow is 65536 more
  counterReady = true;              // set global flag for end count period
  }  // end of TIMER2_COMPA_vect

void setup () 
  {
  Serial.begin(115200);       
  Serial.println("Frequency Counter");
  } // end of setup

void loop () 
  {
  // stop Timer 0 interrupts from throwing the count out
  byte oldTCCR0A = TCCR0A;
  byte oldTCCR0B = TCCR0B;
  TCCR0A = 0;    // stop timer 0
  TCCR0B = 0;    

  startCounting (500);  // how many ms to count for

  while (!counterReady) 
     { }  // loop until count over

  // adjust counts by counting interval to give frequency in Hz
  float frq = (timerCounts *  1000.0) / timerPeriod;

  Serial.print ("Frequency: ");
  Serial.print ((unsigned long) frq);
  Serial.println (" Hz.");

  // restart timer 0
  TCCR0A = oldTCCR0A;
  TCCR0B = oldTCCR0B;

  // let serial stuff finish
  delay(200);
  }   // end of loop
```

---

> Or is there a conventional frequency that digital devices usually use for output?

No.

> Wouldn't it be the case that if Arduino expects 100Hz signal, but the signal is 200Hz it would miss half the inputs? For: (1 0 1 0 0 1...)

No.

Why would it "expect" a frequency? It isn't a person expecting a chocolate cake on its birthday.

---

> So whatever frequency the sensor sends its data in - be it 100Hz or 5Mhz - Arduino is smart enough to read all the voltage signals faithfully?

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "read all the voltage signals" which seems to imply you want to measure the voltage.

> so every 1/100 of a second it varies the voltage (or keeps the old voltage if the next signal is the same as the previous one)

But then you say:

> let's assume that the 1 voltage is high enough (but not too high) for Arduino to register a 1, and the 0 voltage is also within the threshold for Arduino to register a zero (say 5V for HIGH and 0.5V for LOW). It's the frequency of the signal I'm concerned with.

The voltage levels for 0 and 1 are documented in the datasheet. For the Atmega328P for *most* pins they are as follows:

[image: Low and high voltage levels]

You can see that if Vcc is 2.4V or above then LOW is -0.5V to 0.3 * Vcc, which if Vcc is 5V then a LOW is -0.5 to 1.5V.

Similarly a HIGH is 0.6V * Vcc to Vcc + 0.5, so if Vcc is 5V then a HIGH is 3V to 5.5V.

In between 1.5V and 3V then the digital status would be undefined.

So, if your LOW and HIGH are in those voltage ranges, yes you can detect the frequency of the signal.

I'm not sure about the bit where you said "keeps the old voltage if the next signal is the same as the previous one". That seems to imply that if the signals stay the same (eg. for a second) then the voltage won't change at all, and thus the frequency will be zero.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. So whatever frequency the sensor sends its data in - be it 100Hz or 5Mhz - Arduino is smart enough to read all the voltage signals faithfully? If that's the case, that's encouraging news.. One additional question pls: can you determine the frequency of the sensor from the code - i,e. determine if the sensor is 100Hz, 200Hz etc.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: thanks @nick for all the info. About the last paragraph: wouldn't it be the case that if there's a stream of 1s and not 0s for a whole second, then the voltage graph would look like a horizontal line of 5V (basically like DC of 5V) for that 1 sec.)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Another method if it's helpful to the world:

Using inspiration from https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-read-frequency-with-arduino/528143/2

I am just measuring the seconds using micros() between each up or down portion of the waveform, multiplying the time by 2 to get the full period (assuming a duty cycle of 50%). And then inverting the full period to calculate the frequency.

I was using a Teensy 4.1 for this.

```
// READ FREQUENCY FROM A DIGITAL INPUT PIN SKETCH

// this cannot be used when the FreqMeasure.h toolbox is used if on teensy
// https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqMeasure.html

// define your digital input pin
#define inputPin 22 

// initialize variables for the frequency reading function
boolean inputState = false; boolean lastInputState = false;
long lastTime; long period; double freq;

// the frequency reading function
double readFrequency(){
  inputState = digitalRead(inputPin);

  if (inputState != lastInputState) {
    period = micros() - lastTime; // in microseconds
    freq = 1/(2*period*pow(10,-6)); // conversion to Hz

    lastInputState = inputState;
    lastTime = micros(); 
  }
  return freq; // always return frequency even if it hasn't changed state... 
}

// label the pin
void setup() {
  // Serial.begin(115200); // uncomment & adjust for Arduino - I was using a Teensy.
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
}

// call the function and print the output at full speed
void loop() {
  Serial.print("Frequency:"); Serial.println(readFrequency());
  // works even if I put a delay in here (e.g., delay(1) millisecond)
}
```

[image: My serial monitor output]